# Kendo UI DataSource not triggering transport.destroy

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI with ASP.NET Web API. There is a ProjectsController that has all the necessary methods.

My issue is that when I click on `Delete` button, Kendo UI grid will raise `remove()` event, but `DataSource` never invokes `transport.destroy`. Rather, it seems that `tansport.create` is being invoked. In `transport.parameterMap` I can see that the operation is **create** instead of **destroy**.

Here is a sample JavaScript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var apiUrl = '/api/projects/';
    var dataType = 'json';

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        batch: true,
        autoSync: false,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: apiUrl,
                dataType: dataType,
                type: "GET"
            },
            update: {
                url: apiUrl,
                dataType: dataType,
                type: "PUT"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: apiUrl,
                type: "DELETE"
            },
            create: {
                url: apiUrl,
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: dataType,
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                console.log("Operation: " + operation);
                if (operation === "create" && data.models) {
                    for (var i in data.models) {
                        var model = data.models[i];

                        if (model.ProjectId === 0) {
                            return kendo.stringify(model);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (operation === "destroy") {
                    console.log("Data.Models: " + data.models);
                    console.log("Data.id: " + data.ProjectId);
                    return { id: data.ProjectId };
                }

                return data;
            }
        },
        schema: {
            id: "ProjectId",
            model: {
                fields: {
                    ProjectId: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false, defaultValue: 0 },
                    ProjectName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                    Status: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                    IsActive: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: false,
        serverFiltering: false,
        serverSorting: false
    });

    $("#projectsGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        groupable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        editable: "popup",
        columns: [
            { field: "ProjectId", width: 30, title: "ID" },
            { field: "ProjectName", width: 180, title: "Project" },
            { field: "Status", width: 90, title: "Status" },
            { field: "IsActive", width: 40, title: "Is Active", type: "boolean", template: '<input type="checkbox" #if (IsActive) {# checked="checked" #}# disabled="disabled" />' },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp", width: "80px" }
        ],

        remove: function (e) {
            console.log("Delete button clicked.");
            console.log("Project ID: " + e.model.ProjectId);
            //dataSource.remove(e.model);
            //dataSource.sync();
        }
    });
});
```

Web API works fine when requests are issued via Fiddler, but Kendo UI Grid shows:

```
POST http://localhost:port/api/Projects
```

when it should be `DELETE`.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your datasource, you have the **batch** flag set to true, this means the datasource will make the call only after you tell it to, e.g calling sync(). 
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-batch

As well as

Make sure you have defined Id in the model, as OnaBai explained here [Why does the KendoUI Grid Transport Create event gets raised multiple times, and even when the action is Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662223/why-does-the-kendoui-grid-transport-create-event-gets-raised-multiple-times-and) , your id is outside the model, should be in  :

```js
   model: {
        id: "ProductID",
        fields: {
            ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually this is not the case. I can see that the call towards Web API is being made (regardless of whether I call `sync()` or if `autoSync` is set to true. I tried setting batch to false, but that caused another problem with `transport.create`. The problem is that deleting does not raise `transport.destroy`. It keeps raising `transport.create` when I delete an item.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Try to look at this post OnaBai's answer explaines the requirement of Id in your model which seems you did not defined :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662223/why-does-the-kendoui-grid-transport-create-event-gets-raised-multiple-times-and

Comment: That's it. Thanks! Adding id inside of a model is the solution.

Answer (score 4):

if someone has defined the `id` in `model` as answered in above ,but dataSource not triggering transport.destroy yet ,below configuration could be helpful:

```
editable: {
..
mode: "inline", //or "popup
...
}
//or
editable: "inline" //or "popup"
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/transport-destroy-of-grid-editor-is-not-working

Comment: This was the case for me as well - destroy won't get triggered if editable=false. +1