# Kendo UI Grid not reaching Post on Controller

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have looked at an example [Kendo grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing.html) here, and another one [on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/606682/Kendo-Grid-In-Action) and a thread [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383938/kendo-ui-datasource-not-triggering-transport-destroy?lq=1), but I don't seem to find the error. I'm not very knowledgeable with javascript or HTML, so I expect it to be a simple mistake on my part.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var baseURL = "/api/LeaveTypes",
        leaveTypes = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        autoSync: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: baseURL + "?getAll=true",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "GET"
            },
            update: {
                url: baseURL,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },

        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: {type: "number", editable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                    Description: { type: "string", editable: false, validation: { required: true } },                       
                    IsEssLeaveType: { type: "boolean", editable: true, },
                    ColourRGB: {type: "string",  editable: true, nullable: true }
                }
            }
        }
    });


    $(".leavetypesgrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: leaveTypes,
        toolbar: ["save"],
        columns: [{
            field: "Id",
            title: "Leave Type ID"
        }, {
            field: "Description",
            title: "Leave Type"
        }, {
            field: "IsESSLeaveType",
            template: '<input type="checkbox" #= IsESSLeaveType ? "checked=checked" : "" # ></input>',
            title: "Flagged for ESS",
        }, {
            field: "ColourRGB",
            title: "Colour"
        }
        ],
        scrollable: false,
        editable: {
            update: true
        }
    });
});
```

I am trying to get it to work in JSFiddle, but since I'm quite new to it, I'm still struggling to get the data source disconnected from the Controller that I'm currently using to populate the grid with, and connecting it to sample data.

Here is the Controller's Post method:

```
public SimpleResult Post(List<LeaveCalendarLeaveType> leaveTypesList)
{
  return ESSLeaveDataManager.SaveLeaveTypes(leaveTypesList);
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Oh, and I should add that my Post method in the Controller looks like:

public SimpleResult Post(List<LeaveCalendarLeaveType> leaveTypesList)

Should it rather contain string parameters? Just wondering how it would know to send a list of LeaveCalendarLeaveType objects...

Comment: please edit your post and update with controller method..as i suspects that you are using [post] attribute on your controller method and get in Jquery....

Comment: @Mikrur, did you check if your browser is triggering any POST when you do the update? I would do that the first because with this you might focus on searching the problem in the browser (JavaScript) or in the server.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I noticed is that you have two data sources defined. One called `dataSource` and another called `leaveTypes`. You are only setting the datasource on your grid to `leaveTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your MVC route so that it goes to the action named Post() when `/api/LeaveTypes` is called? Otherwise, the `url` for the `update` config should be `/api/LeaveTypes/Post`